# IntelliJ not registering file type with correct plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, puppet

**Edit:** Making title more generic as this situation could apply to any file type.

I am brand new to Puppet and was given the task of adding a new Puppet configuration file. I added a new file, but it either contained a syntax error, had the wrong extension or both (I don't remember), and I believe that caused the file to not register with the plugin. However, even after fixing the syntax error and ensuring the .pp extension, the file is not registering. If I add a new .pp file, it registers right away.

I tried deleting the file and adding it again, but it still won't register, which leads me to believe there is a metadata file somewhere keeping track of which files to register and which to ignore.

I've looked through the the `.idea` folder for mentions of the file but all I see are entries in the `workspace.xml` under the `ChangeListManager` and `FileEditorManager`.

I also tried cloning the repository again but it still doesn't register. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the entire file name had somehow been associated with a text file.

File -> Settings -> File Types -> Recognized File Types -> Text

Located the file name and removed it. The file registered as a Puppet file.